# Amazon EC2 - Create private AMI from snapshot

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm having a really hard time. This is where I am. I have created an EC2 instance, installed my configs and taken a snapshot. I now want to turn this snapshot into an AMI that I can start new instances from scratch with the same code and configs.

> - This is what I have tried:
> - Went to my snapshot
> - Clicked "Create Image"
> - On the "Block Device Mapping" click EBS
> - Then select my snapshot as Device: /dev/sdb

The error I get when I try to do this is:

```
Multiple snapshots with Marketplace codes are not permitted.
```

Has anyone has this before and fixed it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use an Amazon AMI to start with, or one from the Amazon Marketplace? AMIs created by 3rd parties can have restrictions set that prevent users from cloning them and not paying the creator fees.

More details from :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-AttachVolume.html

If a volume has an AWS Marketplace product code:

- The volume can only be attached to the root device of a stopped instance.
- You must be subscribed to the AWS Marketplace code that is on the volume.
- The configuration (instance type, operating system) of the instance must support that specific AWS Marketplace code. For example, you cannot take a volume from a Windows instance and attach it to a Linux instance.
- AWS Marketplace product codes are copied from the volume to the instance.